# Using cat command in java process is secure to use?

Tags: java, sh

We have the below lines of code in our application.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/sudo /opt/infra/bin/readPrivateKey.sh");
BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
…
pvtKey = keys.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Shell file has cat command to execute rsa file. Is it safe and secure to execute the cat command from java? Results will be consistent at all the time? We ought to follow this approach as we don't have permission to access rsa file directly from java.

Answer (score 1):

Results will be as consistent as your  file system. But this is not how you manage  private keys on java program -  there are keystores for it. Here you just read plain file via some programs  - with all the implications